# Using pandas loc in hy

Tags: pandas, hy

I want to do the following in hy:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
5           5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4  setosa
6           4.6          3.4           1.4          0.3  setosa
7           5.0          3.4           1.5          0.2  setosa
8           4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2  setosa
9           4.9          3.1           1.5          0.1  setosa"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s), sep="\s+")

df.loc[df.sepal_length > 4.5]
```

How do I do the last sentence?

I have tried `(.loc df (> df.sepal_length 4.5))`

but it just returns a locindexer.

Comment: With this tagging it will probably be very difficult to attract viewers.

Comment: How should I improve it :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Using the [`.` macro](http://docs.hylang.org/en/latest/language/api.html#id1):

   ```
   (. df loc [(> df.sepal-length 4.5)])
   ```
2. Using `get`:

   ```
   (get df.loc (> df.sepal-length 4.5))
   ```

Protip: always try running `hy2py` on your Hy files. It shows you what the resulting Python looks like. The output isn't always valid syntax, but it shows you what gets compiled into what. Both of these get compiled down to `df.loc[(df.sepal_length > 4.5)]`.

One more thing: notice I used `sepal-length`. Hy converts dashes in identifiers to underscores, so that's the same thing as `sepal_length`, but it's considered better style.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat You're welcome! Next time you have a question, try the [Hy mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hylang-discuss).